# Integral of the gradient of a semilinear function.

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, integration

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a semilinear map so that for any $k\in \mathbb{R}$ the surface $\partial C_k^+=\{x:k=u(x)\}$ is contained in the union of finitely many hyperplanes.

If $\mu_{n-1}$ is the standard measure in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ then we can define 
for a subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ contained in the union of finitely many hyperplanes and hyperspherical surfaces, $\mu_{n-1}(U)$ to be the sum of the measures in the varius $n-1$ dimensional components.

What I don't understand is the following:

$$\int_{C_k^+\cap B(0,1)} |\nabla u| dx = \int_k^\infty \mu_{n-1}(B(0,1)\cap \partial C_t^+)dt$$

Somehow the gradient disappears, I understand that $$C_k^+\cap B(0,1)=\cup_{t=k}^\infty (B(0,1)\cap \partial C_t^+) $$

but can't proceed.

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C_k^+$ means $\{x: u(x)\geq k\}$, then [Coarea formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) reads:
$$
\int_{C_k^+\cap B(0,1)} |\nabla u| dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mu_{n-1}(\{x\in B(0,1): u(x)=t\})dt \\
= \int_{k}^\infty \mu_{n-1}(\{x\in B(0,1): u(x)=t\})dt = \int_k^\infty \mu_{n-1}(B(0,1)\cap \partial C_t^+)dt.
$$
To see why the gradient disappeared, I drew a little illustration here:

[image: coarea]

The reason $|\nabla u|$ disappear because we view it as the normal vector for the level curve $\{(x,u(x)): u(x) = t\}$.

Comment: thank you! the picture is very helpful and I did not know about Coarea formula.

Comment: @Moritzplatz Another famous formula using level set to do the integral is called Layer cake, you might wanna know as well:)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation

Comment: thanks! so the fact that u was semilinear did not actually matter? (or is it just that the n-1 dim. measure only makes sense since w is semilinear?)

Comment: @Moritzplatz Sorry for the late reply, semilinearity does serve as a sufficient condition for the hypersurface to be measurable under $(n-1)$-Lebesgue measure.